# create a directive to enable focus on input fields

Tags: angular, focus, directive

I try to activate the focus in many of the inputs in my application. Instead of duplicating code, I thought I would create a custom directive but I can’t.
If someone can help me..
Here's my bad code :
directive:

```
import { AfterViewInit, Directive, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appFocus]'
})
export class FocusDirective implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('zone') zoneInput: ElementRef;
  constructor() { }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
     this.zoneInput.nativeElement.focus();
  }

}
```

in a template:

```
        <div>
            <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" appearance="fill">
                <mat-label>Saisie code barre</mat-label>
                <input appFocus matInput formControlName="barcode" placeholder="EAN...">
            </mat-form-field>
        </div>
```

Thank you very much

Comment: You were close. Pass the element in the constructor, `constructor(private host: ElementRef) {}` and then you can access it with `this.host.nativeElement.focus();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close!

```
  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.el.nativeElement.focus();
  }
```

You need to actually pass the element in so that you have access to the native Element to focus on, not the zoneInput. You may or may not need to wrap in a setTimeout, but this should get you what you need.

Comment: thanks a lot, it compiles but I have the following error:
ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value for 'mat-form-field-should-float': 'false'. Current value: 'true'..

Comment: Looks unrelated, I don't see that mat-form-field-should-float anywhere in the snippet you gave us. That looks like something you can search for and find where it is being used. It's most likely being used in a AfterView or AfterContent init and the value is changing before doCheck. May wanna make sure those are only referenced in OnInit instead.

Comment: Actually, you can probably change the ngAfterViewInit() to ngOnInit() I assume that, because it has focus, you have a float label that needs to show up.

Comment: I found the origin of the problem without understanding it. There is a tag mat-form-field that contains the property appearance="fill". when I remove this property, the error disappears...I modified my post to show you all the html of the form

Comment: Yeah, so more than likely, something is changing on that field that is triggering that value to be false (probably focus), when its checked initially, its false, but after the page finishes rendering, its true, so it throws that error. Instead of making that focus in afterViewInit, just throw it in OnInit or wrap it in a setTimeout.

Comment: Yeah, it works with onInit(), I'm going to try whit a setTimeout().  thanks again..